# Call to JavaScript setTimeout not being called 10 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a JavaScript/jQuery code function that is supposed to call itself up to ten times if there is no data available (determined by web service call). I have implemented the code but the logging inside the web service call indicates that it is called only 1 or 2 times. What is the error in this code?

```
 function CallIsDataReady(input) {
            var timer;
            var count = 0;

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/IsDataReady",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: input,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data) {
                        setTimeout(function(inputInner) {
                            CallIsDataReady(inputInner);
                            count++;
                            if (count == 10) {
                                clearInterval(timer);
                                count = 0;
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    } else {
                        console.log("data returned - returning true");
                        //Continue as data is ready
                        var tableView = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                        GetDataFromServer(0, tableView.get_pageSize());
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errThrown) {
                    console.log("AJAX call failed in CallIsDataReady");
                    console.log(errThrown);
                }
            });
        }
```

**EDIT: It should try up to ten times and then quit, not go on to the GetDataFromServer. It should return an error. How can I do that**?

Comment: declare the count variable outside of the function

Comment: This is strange. Why this `timer` on which you call `clearInterval` ? Is that really your code ?

Comment: I don't think you ever assign a value to `inputInner`.

Comment: Declare `timer` outside the function, and don't forget to set it `timer = setTimeout(function()...`

Comment: To be clear, both "timer" and "count" need to be external to the "CallIsDataReady" function. Otherwise, each call to the function will reset them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**setTimeout** is meant to trigger a function call **once, and only once**.

Repeat call to setTimeout from within your timeouted callback if you want this to work:

```
function CallIsDataReady(input) {
    var timer;
    var count = 0;

    function callWebService(){
        console.log('calling webservice');
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/IsDataReady",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: input,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('count = ' + count);
                console.log('data = ' + data);
                if (!data){
                    if(count < 10) {
                        count++;
                        setTimeout(callWebService, 1000);
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }else{
                    console.log("data returned - returning true");
                    //Continue as data is ready
                    var tableView = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                    GetDataFromServer(0, tableView.get_pageSize());
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errThrown) {
                console.log("AJAX call failed in CallIsDataReady");
                console.log(errThrown);
            }
        });
    };

    callWebService();
}
```

Comment: This causes an infinite loop and it never comes back

Comment: My bad, try this edited version. You really have to repeat calls to setTimeout

Comment: Did you change the name to callWebService?

Comment: among other things, yes

Comment: It seems to want inputInner to be defined

Comment: And now i also removed the inputInner parameter which i had left out

Comment: Still executes only once

Comment: does your browser console displays an error like 'count undefined'?

Comment: no it displays nothing. Worse yet, it seems after one time itt calls GetDataFromServer instead of looping, Help!

Comment: I did see one run where it executed ten times but usually it executes only once and then calls GetDataFromServer. I left out that it should stop after ten times and return an error not go on.

Comment: i had missed something with the stop condition, you may try this again and i also added some output to the console.

Comment: That's it! It executes 10 times and stops. Now all I need is something that displays an error after 10 times. How do I do that?

Comment: alert('an error occured') right after count=0;
Don't forget to mark my answer as correct pls.

Answer (score 1):

`count` is being reset every time `CallIsDataReady` is called.

Replace:

```
function CallIsDataReady(input) {
    var timer;
    var count = 0;
```

With:

```
var count = 0;
function CallIsDataReady(input) { // You won't need the `timer` variable
```

This will set `count` to `0` before the first call of `CallIsDataReady`. Then, each call, the `count` will be incremented.

Now, to handle that counter properly, replace:

```
if (!data) {
    setTimeout(function(inputInner) {
        CallIsDataReady(inputInner);
        count++;
        if (count == 10) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            count = 0;
        }
    }, 1000);
```

With:

```
if (!data && count !== 10) {
    setTimeout(function(input) {
        CallIsDataReady(input);
        count++;
    }, 1000);
```

Now, I'm not sure what `inputInner` is supposed to be, so I replaced that with `input`. If you want a different variable to be passed to subsequent calls, you'll have to assign a value to `inputInner`.

Comment: And timer too. And the strange thing about inputInner. And he should use clearTimeout, not clearInterval.

Comment: I'm still getting it called just once not up to 10 times. I have the data source shut off. It should try up to 10 times

Comment: @user2471435: What's the console displaying?

Comment: Nothing in the console

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making `timer` and `count` into global variables, I think you need to assign a value to `inputInner` when you execute it:

```
                if (!data) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      function(inputInner) {
                        CallIsDataReady(inputInner);
                        count++;
                        if (count == 10) {
                            clearInterval(timer);
                            count = 0;
                        }
                      }(input);
                    }, 1000);
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. `setTimeout` calls function only once after certain amount of time. `setInterval` will be calling your function in intervals until you call `clearInterval`.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
  timer=  setInterval(function(inputInner) {
       CallIsDataReady(inputInner);
       count++;
       if (count == 10) {
           clearInterval(timer);
           count = 0;
       }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: That's not the problem here. Look at the comments.

Comment: He calls the function that calls `setTimeout` within `setTimeout`.

Comment: My point is you don't need to setTimeout to achieve the result.

Comment: Yes, you need to because you'd better wait for the last call to be OK before you start the timer again.

Comment: How about you start setInterval when your call fails?

Comment: What he means is, what happens if the ajax call takes longer than 10 seconds?  The OP wants the 10 second delay to start again *after* the ajax call is complete.  This is perfectly normal practice.

Comment: got it than I did not get the answer right. Misread, thought he wants 10 attempts. my answer is invalid.